# Javascript Alert and textbox enter

Tags: javascript, events, textbox, alert, keypress

I am having problem with javascript alert and a textbox listening to enter keypress event.
At the form when something is wrong I show user an javascript alert displaying what is wrong, if user press enter key javascript is calling event on textbox too.
How can I correct this problem?

Thanks in advance

Patricia

Comment: Please share us your code.

Comment: explain a little more about your problem too

Comment: Pressing ENTER on a textbox in a form will submit the form. Please show the relevant JS and HTML you have.

Answer (score 0):

JS code:

```
   handleChange: function(e) {
        if (e.key == 'Enter') {
           e.preventDefault();
        }
```

Html code :

```
     <div>
        <Input type="text"
           ref = "input"
           placeholder="anyText"
           onKeyPress={this.handleChange}
        />
     </div>
```